# Find parent child loop in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Parent Child Relations table in MySQL that has the following columns:
id, pid, cid, value. Created like this:

```
create table PCRELATIONS(
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 pid char(1) NOT NULL, 
 cid char(1) NOT NULL, 
 value varchar(10),   
 PRIMARY KEY ( id ) 
);
```

Here, `id` is the surrogate key, `pid` and `cid` are fks from another table, and `value` is varchar. I know pid and cid should be int but I am using char here just to make it easier to visualize the problem without causing confusion due to too many 1s and 2s.

I need to find all the loops in the table which involve exactly three nodes i.e. A->B->C->A.

For example, if the table has the following data:

| id | pid | cid | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | AB |
| 2 | B | C | BC |
| 3 | C | A | CA1 |
| 4 | C | A | CA2 |
| 5 | C | D | CD |

Here are the insert queries:

```
insert into PCRELATIONS values(0, 'A', 'B', 'AB');
insert into PCRELATIONS values(0, 'B', 'C', 'BC');
insert into PCRELATIONS values(0, 'C', 'A', 'CA1');
insert into PCRELATIONS values(0, 'C', 'A', 'CA2');
insert into PCRELATIONS values(0, 'C', 'D', 'CD');
```

This data has two loops involving A->B->C->A because there are two paths from C to A.

I am trying to get this result:

```
leg1, leg2, leg3, p1id, p2id, p3id, val1, val2, val3
1, 2, 3, A, B, C, AB, BC, CA1,
1, 2, 4, A, B, C, AB, BC, CA2,
```

I was thinking that the following query will do it but it is returning too many rows. Where am I going wrong?

```
select x.id as leg1, y.id as leg2, z.id as leg3, 
  x.pid as pid1, y.pid as pid2, z.pid as pid3, 
  x.value as val1, y.value as val2, z.value as val3  
from pcrelations x 
inner join pcrelations y on x.cid=y.pid 
inner join pcrelations z on y.cid=z.pid 
where z.cid=x.pid;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: Bad habbits to kick: [using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @D-Shih
  I am using Mysql 8.0.11 on windows for local dev but the query has to run on AWS where I am running 10.2.38-MariaDB

Comment: Agree with you, @stu but here it is a self join and the table, data, and query is for illustration purpose only.

Comment: @Akina, I have updated the question as suggested. thx.

Comment: *I need to find all the loops in the table which involve exactly three nodes i.e. A->B->C->A.* You need any 3-node loops or 3-node loops which includes some definite node (for example, node `'A'`)? You need these loops starting from any node or from some definite node (for example, from node `'A'`, or from a node with the least `pid`)?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the value of the joined table is bigger.

> ```
> select 
>   t1.id as leg1, t2.id as leg2, t3.id as leg3 
> -- , t1.cid as cid1, t2.cid as cid2, t3.cid as cid3
> , t1.pid as pid1, t2.pid as pid2, t3.pid as pid3
> , t1.value as val1, t2.value as val2, t3.value as val3  
> from pcrelations t1
> inner join pcrelations t2
>   on t2.pid = t1.cid 
>  and t2.value > t1.value
> inner join pcrelations t3 
>   on t3.pid = t2.cid 
>  and t3.cid = t1.pid 
>  and t3.value > t2.value;
> ```

| leg1 | leg2 | leg3 | pid1 | pid2 | pid3 | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | A | B | C | AB | BC | CA1 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | A | B | C | AB | BC | CA2 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60313b5c6082354f7a5b343b133c2885)*

Comment: Position-dependent, i.e. non-deterministic. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7544e17f93f78405dd24158a1b263b97 (2nd source row simply moved down).

Comment: @Akina Good point. Using the value as tie-breaker works also, and doesn't depend on order of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

You need strictly 3-node loops, recursive CTE not needed in this case.

```sql
SELECT t1.id    leg1, t2.id    leg2, t3.id    leg3 
     , t1.pid   p1id, t2.pid   p2id, t3.pid   p3id
     , t1.value val1, t2.value val2, t3.value val3  
FROM pcrelations t1                       -- 1st level
JOIN pcrelations t2 ON t2.pid = t1.cid    -- join 2nd level
JOIN pcrelations t3 ON t3.pid = t2.cid    -- join 3rd level
WHERE t3.cid = t1.pid                     -- check for a loop
  AND t1.pid < t2.pid                     -- select only those loop copy which starts 
  AND t1.pid < t3.pid;                    -- from the node with the least pid value
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c58bdd205e0f61a71b8433cb10c72878

PS. Will not return 3-node loops like `A->A->A->A` (which matches the conditions formally). If you need in these loops then use `<=` in last 2 conditions in WHERE clause.

Comment: Yes, I need exactly three node loops. 
Would this query be faster than the CTE approach (Which looks too intimidating, tbh)? And if I need exactly 4 node loop, would it be advisable to use the same approach? Given that there are about 200,000 records in the table.

Comment: @Priyshrm CTE is preferred, of course, especially if the amount of rows is high (200k is not) and if there are no suitable indices. And CTE is compulsory when the needed level is not static or may vary. If you use CTE with definite needed depth then add level column into the rowset and check recurse depth by it.

Comment: Although the self join query is fine for now, would it be alright if I request you to post the query with CTE approach as well? Just for comparison and performance comparison? Or should I post a new question?